# How can we customize LoadIndicator?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I want to show custom loader or image till my files will upload to server from Drive. How can I set custom loader or image to 'setLoadIndicator'?. I have implemented with Apps Script add-ons for Drive. `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addToUi()` not working as showing error

```
var buttonActionSelect = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("MyMethod").setLoadIndicator(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addToUi()).setParameters({selectedItems: JSON.stringify(selectedItems)});

 
var button = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Upload File')
      .setOnClickAction(buttonActionSelect)
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, load indicators cannot be customized. `CardService` only offers two possible settings: `SPINNER` or `NONE`.

See documentation linked below:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setLoadIndicator(LoadIndicator)